# Front-end project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-2015, gulp, bower

I have a pure front-end project (folder) using the following technologies:

- gulp (with gulpfile.js and gulpfile.config.js)
- bower
- npm
- TypeScript (compiled with gulp using npm package 'gulp-typescript') and configured with a tsconfig.json file.
- the project has a src folder containing the .ts files.
- no .NET framework dependency no C# file to compile.

Everything is well configured and compiling correctly using command line (gulp or npm run).

**Is Visual Studio 2015 able to open and build this kind of projects?**

I have tried a workaround by adding a project.json file in the root folder. VS 2015 created an .xproj after that and succeeded to manage bower and npm dependencies and also to run gulp tasks. but the TypeScript compilation seems broken and VS is using his default compiler (not npm one).

Comment: Try installing the beta version of TypeScript 1.8 - it allows you to override a Visual Studio project's built-in TypeScript configuration with a `tsconfig.json`. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/

Comment: Well I think this is not really the problem. since the tsconfig.json is read by gulp and given to the tsc as a parameter. I only need to the npm typescript compiler not the vs studio one (but how).

Comment: Might be the problem with environment variable PATH. Try print `process.env.PATH` in your gulpfile and see whether VS is adding the folder of its own TypeScript compiler into it.